# Is it possible to read python documentation at iPython terminal?

Tags: ipython

For example, I want to know how the 'shape' function is defined?

```
v.reshape(1,3)
```

At a iPython terminal, can I pull out the documentation of this function easily to read？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`?` and `??` help shortcuts](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/python-ipython-diff.html#accessing-help):

```
In [7]: class Foo:
  ...       def bar(self):
  ...           return 5
  ...

In [8]: f = Foo()

In [9]: f.bar?
Signature: f.bar()
Docstring: <no docstring>
File:      /tmp/<ipython-input-7-092982d55a54>
Type:      method

In [10]: f.bar??
Signature: f.bar()
Docstring: <no docstring>
Source:
    def bar(self):
        return 5
File:      /tmp/<ipython-input-7-092982d55a54>
Type:      method
```

`?f.bar` and `f.bar?` work identically. The source code of functions and modules is only viewable if they're written in Python. Otherwise, you'll just see the docstring.